# TextInputLayout change start icon tint color on focus

Tags: android, xml

How to change startIconDrawable color when the focus is on the TextInputEditText

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text"
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/person_24dp">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:hint="family"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/mediumTextSize" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin:

```
textInputEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
    val color = if (hasFocus) Color.BLUE else Color.GRAY
    textInputLayout.setStartIconTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(color))
}
```

Java:

```
textInputEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        int color = hasFocus ? Color.BLUE : Color.GRAY;
        textInputLayout.setStartIconTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
    }
});
```

Java code can be simplified using lambda expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by `BindingAdapter`

```
@BindingAdapter("startIconTintOnFocus")
fun TextInputLayout.startIconTintOnFocus(textInputEditTextId: Int) {
    val et = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(textInputEditTextId)
    et.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
        val color = if (hasFocus) ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent) else ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red)
        this.setStartIconTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(color))
    }
}
```

set the `startIconTintOnFocus` in `TextInputLayout` and send `TextInputEditText`'s id to it

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/outlinedTextField"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:startIconTint="@color/red"
    startIconTintOnFocus="@{@id/textInputEditText}"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_phone_android_24dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/textInputEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/mediumTextSize"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

thank's to `@miel3k`

Answer (score 1):

**Solution with XML**

Create color Selector for `startIconTint` or `endIconTint`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/text" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/input" android:state_focused="false"/>
</selector>
```

And for TextInputLayout set `startIconTint` or `endIconTint`:

For example:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/passwordLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/login_edit_password"
    app:endIconTint="@color/YOUR_CREATED_COLOR_SELECTOR"
    app:endIconMode="password_toggle">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Without focus: [image]

With focus:         [image]